# JS - Use replace to replace space period with period

Tags: javascript, replace

Using `replace`, how do you replace space period with just period anywhere within text?

Currently I could only figure out searching for space and replacing it with a period, but I need for it to look for a pattern of space + period.  BTW, this pattern is random, so some sentences appear correctly, without the excess space before the period.

Example:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit . Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae elementum curabitur .

So far I have the following, but this is wrong as it replaces all spaces with periods.

```js
cleanData(str) {
  return str.replace(/\s/g, '.');
}
```

Comment: Match a space and period instead of a single `\s` like `\s.`

Comment: Can you give some test cases in the format of `expectedInput -> expectedOutput` so that we can craft the appropriate regex for you please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of regex, but I don't think it's needed in this case.  Maybe you could try something like this:

```
cleanData(str) {
   return str.replaceAll(' .', '.');
}
```